# Compare method (compareTo) returns different results in different JVMs

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable, compareto

I am puzzled: I wrote an comparator which compares dates. However when I run the junit test it returns me different results depending on if I run it in my IDE or in maven?! In my IDE it works and in maven it fails. Using the same 1.8 jvm in both environments however in maven with 1.6 compatibility mode. (Please note this is a legacy project and using java.util.date is bad ...(but this is not the point right now)

Here's the output from the IDE (correct):

`Birthday [id=four, time=Thu Sep 23 20:54:24 CEST 2010]
Birthday [id=six, time=Wed Feb 01 01:01:01 CET 2012]
Birthday [id=five, time=Wed Feb 01 01:01:02 CET 2012]
Birthday [id=three, time=Tue Jan 08 17:30:43 CET 2019]
Birthday [id=one, ]
Birthday [id=two, ]`

And here the output from maven (not correct):

`Birthday [id=four, time=Thu Sep 23 20:54:24 CEST 2010]
Birthday [id=three, time=Tue Jan 08 17:26:25 CET 2019]
Birthday [id=five, time=Wed Feb 01 01:01:02 CET 2012]
Birthday [id=six, time=Wed Feb 01 01:01:01 CET 2012]
Birthday [id=one, ]
Birthday [id=two, ]`

Here's the code (run it in 1.8 for sucess, 1.6 for failure):

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Birthday implements Comparable<Birthday>{

    private String id;
    private Date time;

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public Birthday(String id, Date time) {
        this.id=id;
        this.time=time;
    }
    public Date getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }
    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Birthday o) {   
        //if both are null return 0 for equals
        if(this.time==null && o.getTime()==null) {
            return 0;
        }

        //null birthdays should always be last
        if(this.time==null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(o.getTime() == null) {
            return -1;            
        }
        return this.time.before(o.getTime()) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id+" "+this.time;
    }
}

@Test
public void testTime() {
    Birthday info1 = new Birthday("one",null);
    Birthday info2 = new Birthday("two", null);
    Birthday info3 = new Birthday("three",new Date());
    Birthday info4 = new Birthday("four",new Date(110,8,23,20,54,24));
    Birthday info5 = new Birthday("five",new Date(112,1,1,1,1,2));
    Birthday info6 = new Birthday("six",new Date(112,1,1,1,1,1));

    ArrayList<Birthday> dates = new ArrayList<Birthday>();
    dates.add(info1);
    dates.add(info2);
    dates.add(info4);
    dates.add(info3);
    dates.add(info5);
    dates.add(info6);

    Collections.sort(dates);

    for(Birthday bs: dates) {
        System.out.println(bs);
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(info4, dates.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals(info6, dates.get(1));
    Assert.assertEquals(info7, dates.get(2));
    Assert.assertEquals(info5, dates.get(3));
    Assert.assertEquals(info3, dates.get(4));
    Assert.assertEquals(info1, dates.get(5));
    Assert.assertEquals(info2, dates.get(6));
}
```

What is going on??

Comment: It would be easier for everybody if A) your test would be using **asserts** so that a fail leads to a fail and B) you would have *only* failing cases in your input (or say: one failing, one passing)

Comment: I had asserts in the original test and this is how I detected the problem in the first place. But for readability here I shortended it...

Comment: There is always [mcve]. Why bother with sorting, or asking people to compare toString() results to figure what is going on. Also helps yourself debugging. That is actually what you **want** unit tests for: the fastest path leading to a problem, so you can turn into the debugger and figure what is going on....

Comment: Yes I know MCV - that is why I added code in the first place. But readability is also an important factor. The more code the less answers... And thanks for the hints but the code itself is complete (regarding sucess/failing examples). It just needs to be run in different JVMs...(But I added a hint for that.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
return this.time.before(o.getTime()) ? 0 : 1;
```

if this items time is before the others time, they are equal. This is not reflexive, so you break the requirements for compareTo.

Different JVM implementations can use different sorting algorithms, where one will exhibit this bug, and the other not

Comment: Yes indeed - I found the problem after a bit of analysis... But the effect was quite puzzling in the first place :-)

Comment: Yes, breaking requirements of relational operations can be quite... interresting ;) I once made a equals for timespans, that returned true if two timespans overlap... not a good idea!

Comment: just get the long value and subtract them. reverse order of operands to reverse ordering.

Comment: @mavriksc Since Date values are comparable, use compareTo() instead getting long values and subtracting.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the problem is in the last line of the `compareTo` method.

Since `Date` implements `Comparable`, the easiest fix is:

```
return this.time.compareTo(o.getTime());
```

Comment: If your pace continues like that, you will soon re-overtake me ;-) ... and you will reach 100K before. And then I am even helping you ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `compareTo()` method is flawed.  In the event that neither object's time is `null`, it boils down to

```
        return this.time.before(o.getTime()) ? 0 : 1;
```

but what if `o.time.before(this.getTime())`?  Your `compareTo()` must reliably return -1 in that case, but instead it returns 0.  `java.util.Date` has a natural order, which you might as well use as long as you're relying on that class in the first place:

```
        return this.time.compareTo(o.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem:
The comparator returned 0 (indicating equality) which is not correct:

Should be
`return this.time.before(o.getTime()) ? -1 : 1;`

instead of 
`return this.time.before(o.getTime()) ? 0 : 1;`

And as indicated by John even better:

`return this.time.compareTo(o.getTime());`

And java changed the [sort algorithm](https://dertompson.com/2012/11/23/sort-algorithm-changes-in-java-7/) in JDK 1.7 which probably handles equal values differently. So this came all together in this interesting puzzling case...

Comment: And if the two times are equal?